DevServer is not reloading files after html-bundler-webpack-plugin was installed on WebPack5
Hello Guys I've been working on creating a local dev env using Webpack to develop sites, the devServer.watchFiles was working until I installed the html-bundler-webpack-plugin I've tried all read all documentation everything looks fine but when I edit the html or scss files it does not reload them on the browser automatically. I even added plugins.watchfiles as you can see you below
const path = require('path');
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@scripts': path.join(__dirname, 'src/js'),
      '@styles': path.join(__dirname, 'src/scss'),
      '@images': path.join(__dirname, 'src/images'),
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      // path to templates
      entry: 'src/views/',
      js: {
        // output filename of compiled JavaScript
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // output filename of extracted CSS
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },

      watchFiles: {
      paths: ['./src'],
      files: [/\.(html|ejs|eta)$/],
      ignore: [
    /[\\/](node_modules|dist|test)$/, // ignore standard project dirs
    /[\\/]\..+$/, // ignore hidden dirs and files, e.g.: .git, .idea, .gitignore, etc.
    /package(?:-lock)*\.json$/, // ingnore npm files
    /webpack\.(.+)\.js$/, // ignore Webpack config files
    /\.(je?pg|png|ico|webp|svg|woff2?|ttf|otf|eot)$/, // ignore binary assets
      ],
    }

    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|png|jp?g|svg)/,
        type: 'asset',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[name].[hash:8][ext]', // save to file images >= 2 KB
        },
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 2 * 1024, // inline images < 2 KB
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
 
  // enable live reload
  devServer: {
    static:{
     directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    watchFiles: {
    paths: ['src/**/*.*'], 
    options: {
        usePolling: true, 
    },
    },
    port:3000, 
    open: true, 
    // hot:true, 
    // compress:true, 
    // HistoryApiFallback:true,
    
  },
    // watchOptions: {
    // poll:true, 
    // ignored: /node_modules/, 
    // },

};


What OS are you using? Not reloading watched files is typically an inotify issue. Have you tried these troubleshooting tips?

Thank you @phil I am using macOS Mojave version 10.14.6, I will look into those, but it was working before I installed the html-bundler-webpack-plugin it does not matter ?

@Legend10 can you please create a small repo with the reproducible issue? Try please disable the watchFiles in the bundler plugin option (this is should be used for very rare use case). The devServer. watchFiles is correct.

@biodiscus thank you so much I am creating a repo from scratch and commenting every step, I will let know how it goes. Once again thank you for the help!
